# Using a variable in GitLab CI inside a POST request

Tags: json, variables, curl, gitlab-ci

I can't understand what YML does to my script and why everything reads as text. Can you please explain why everything is read as text and how to insert variables here?

```
  script:
    - >
      curl --silent --show-error
      --request POST 
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
      --url "https:webhook"
      --data '{"@type": "MessageCard","@context": "http://schema.org/extensions","themeColor": "0076D7","summary": "New changes ","sections": [{"activityTitle": "New changes","activitySubtitle": "Some Build","activityImage": "png","facts": [{"name": "Assigned to","value": "$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN"}, {"name": "Due date","value": "$CI_JOB_STARTED_AT"}, {"name": "Status","value": "$CI_JOB_STATUS"}],}]}'
```

The result is something like

[image: Mistake]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the triple funny quotes around the variables. Example: `"'"$CI_JOB_STARTED_AT"'"`. A more cleaner way would be to move the curl command to a shell script.

Comment: How can im " move the curl command to a shell script."? Can you show me example?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of difference between single and double quotes in bash - when you use single quotes the variables aren’t going to be expanded.

So, here is a workaround for the instance:

```yaml
script:
    - >
      curl --silent --show-error
      --request POST 
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
      --url "https:webhook"
      --data "'{"@type": "MessageCard","@context": "http://schema.org/extensions","themeColor": "0076D7","summary": "New changes ","sections": [{"activityTitle": "New changes","activitySubtitle": "Some Build","activityImage": "png","facts": [{"name": "Assigned to","value": "$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN"}, {"name": "Due date","value": "$CI_JOB_STARTED_AT"}, {"name": "Status","value": "$CI_JOB_STATUS"}],}]}'"
```